# Installing Gromacs: Error in last step while using command $source /path/to/bin/GMXRC

Tags: shell, unix, installation

While installing [GROMACS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GROMACS) I get the error `goto: command not found` when I try to run the last command in the installation process where we can source the file by source */usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC*.

The solution will probably be very simple but I have a mental block moving ahead. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: doesn't that error give you ideas? I think `[t]csh` is the only shell that support `goto`. oh, and MS DOS `.bat` files. So are  you running the install with the correct interpreter? Incidentally, this Q lacks any information that would help a reader reproduce your problem, AND it's not really a coding-program question, so it will probably be voted closed. Maybe more appropriate on http://superuser.com . Good luck.

Comment: Re "source the file by source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC": please clarify whether those last two words are a single command or not, i.e.: `source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC`